# Unix to Sqlplus - Log the SQL statement about to execute and result of execution

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, logging

I am on AIX using `ksh`.  Created a unix script which generates the *CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW* ... and *GRANT* .. statements, which are placed in a single *.txt* file.  Now I need to execute the contents in the file (there are around 300 view creation and grant statements) in Oracle and I need to log the sql statement that is about to execute and the feedback of Oracle whether the view is created or not..
My excerpt goes as

```
sqlplus -s username/password@servername <<EOF
SET ECHO ON;
SET NEWPAGE 0;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET LINESIZE 200;
SET LONG 10000000;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SET HEADING OFF;
SET FEEDBACK ON;
SET VERIFY ON;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
 
SPOOL ${drctry}/${v_timestamp}_sql_execution_log.txt
@${drctry}/${v_date}_sql_statements.txt
SPOOL OFF;

EXIT;

EOF
```

If the contents of the file _${v_date}*sql_statements.txt* is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;  
GRANT SELECT ON V_TABLE1 TO USER1;
...
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE300 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE300;
GRANT SELECT ON V_TABLE300 TO USER300;
```

Expected output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
View created
GRANT SELECT ON V_TABLE1 TO USER1;
Grant succeeded
...
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE300 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE300;
View created
GRANT SELECT ON V_TABLE300 TO USER300;
Grant succeeded
```

After some search, noticed List option;  But it only records only the last statement that was executed if we have more than 1 statement, which doesn't fit here.  In *Teradata Bteq* the *ECHOREQuired* attribute can be set to *ON* for this task.  But I am not sure in Oracle. Also tried
`sqlplus -s username/password@servername <<EOF > ${drctry}/${v_timestamp}_unix_sql_log.txt`  But still no luck.  Will change the password hardcode once I overcome this issue;

Comment: Just curious is this part of a refresh process or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-s[ilent]` option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#sthref223):

> Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus.

So by including the `-s` flag you are overriding the `set echo on` directive.

If you omit that then the commands are echoed in the spool file, but (a) you also see the banner on stdout and (b) you see the `SQL>` prompt and the script name `spool off` echoed too. You can fix the first part by redirecting output, with the risk you may miss something you care about if there is a problem, by changing your shell command to do:

```
sqlplus -s username/password@servername >/dev/null <<EOF
```

And you can *partly* fix the spooled output by changing the prompt, adding:

```
SET SQLPROMPT ""
```

With those changes the shell sees no output, and the spool file contains:

```
@/path/to/v_date_sql_statements.txt
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

View created.

GRANT SELECT ON V_TABLE1 TO USER1;

Grant succeeded.

...

SPOOL OFF;
```

You could potentially post-process that to remove the first and last line, and (if you want) blank lines. You can also hide the script name by including the text file in the heredoc instead of using start/@:

```
SPOOL ${drctry}/${v_timestamp}_sql_execution_log.txt
`cat ${drctry}/${v_date}_sql_statements.txt`
SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: Perfect @Alex Poole;  Thank you for _sqlprompt_ option too.  There were line numbers being displayed and got rid of them using _sqlnumber_ attribute in case if any other user does need it.

Comment: Right, I didn't try any multi-line statements. Good addition.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sqplus bash script to do that.
link to github: https://github.com/javierB-/ORACLE.git
It create two files, one with the sql sentences, and the other with the sql sentences and their output.

The script core is:

```
tee -a $FOUT $FOUT_TRAZA | sqlplus $@ |  tee -a $FOUT
```

I use  the script throught the alias:

```
alias sqlpluss='$ADMIN_HOME/oracle/sqlpluss.sh'
```

it's in spanish, i have traslated the output to write here:

```
 sqlpluss
  USE ONLY INTERACTIVELY:
  sqlplus enriched to save input and output trace.
 Use:
  sqlpluss [-f fout] user/password@conection @scripts ...
     (fout will be opened in add mode and it will default to yyyymmdd.log)
      
summary:
  tee -a fout | sqlplus $@ |  tee -a fout
```

the full script its too long to paste here, but if someone want, i'll do it.

Comment: Maybe add it to a gist in github and share a link?

Comment: here it is! only one year later!! 
https://github.com/javierB-/ORACLE.git